# How do I use a wildcard asterisk CSS selector in SASS?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, wildcard

How do I use a "*" CSS wildcard selector when using SASS?  For instance, how would I make the following CSS code SASSy?

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

### Edit:

Thank you for the answers so far, but let me clarify.  I realize that there are many different perspectives on the code sample.  The code sample is not the question.  The question remains, how do I use the `*` selector?  The SASS parser throws a syntax error when it encounters the `*` and says that it encountered `*`, but expected a selector.  I'm using Sass 3.4.19 (Selective Steve) on Mac OSX 10.9.5.

### Edit 2:

I have found the solution.  The error was being cause by a missing `;` in a file that was included on the line immediately preceding the `*` code block.  Such is the life of dealing with other people's code.  I'm going to award the answer to @torazaburo since he was the only one who actually addressed the question and made me rethink other possibilities.

Comment: Why do you want to make it "SASSy"? What do you think "SASSy" means? Why would you think that the `*` would work differently in a CSS preprocessor than in regular CSS? By the way, `box-sizing` requires no vendor prefix.

Comment: The SASS parser does not allow the `*` selector.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, wildcard selector does not throw a syntax error: http://sassmeister.com/gist/2cc406d17d20904bfddd

Comment: Thank you for trying, @cimmanon.  Please see my last edit.

Comment: You're not obligated to accept an answer if it didn't actually answer your question.  Questions caused by typos should be closed as not reproducible.  If you had an actual problem with the code you wrote you should have explained what the *actual problem was* rather than having us sit here and guess what you wanted.

Comment: @cimmanon But it did.  It addressed the fact that the `*` selector is perfectly legal in SASS.  That caused me to go looking somewhere else for the error.  My question was how to use the `*` character and the answer was to simply use it.

Comment: But that's my point.  "Is X valid?" is a terrible question that can only be answered by either "Yes" or "No".  You could have answered it by testing it for yourself.  torazaburo should have known better than to answer such a question in the first place.

Comment: @cimmanon My very first comment on the question was *Why would you think that the `*` would work differently in a CSS preprocessor than in regular CSS?*, so that would have been a really good time for the OP to pipe up about the `*` not working for him at all, in which case things would have gone in a much different direction. As it was, the question simply seemed to be about modifying some CSS that happened to involved the asterisk to be more SASS like.

Comment: @torazaburo If you thought the question was "refactor this code for me", you should have voted to close as *unclear*.  If you thought the question was "why doesn't X work?" when X works perfectly fine, you should have voted to close as *off-topic > no MCVE* or *unclear*.  There is absolutely no circumstance in which this question should have been answered at all by anyone, especially when the problem ended up being a typo in some unrelated code.

Comment: @cimmanon Nice to have such firm opinions. I thought the question was "how do I use `*` in SASS", which was what it said. My telepathic powers obviously failed to detect that this was a typo-in-disguise problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's little here that SASS can help you with. You do not need vendor prefixes. Just write

```
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Whether to write `*::before` or `::before` is a matter of personal preference.

The **I-must-use-SASS** mentality would be to say I **must** write the

```
*::before
```

rule as

```
* { 
  &::before
```

because I **must** use nesting, no matter what, just because I can. Actually, not. Your CSS is often much cleaner with less (or zero) nesting. (Often it's clearer with no SASS at all, but that's a topic for another day.)

> How do I use a `*` CSS wildcard selector when using SASS?

There is nothing special about the `*` to SASS. It's just another selector. You use it like you use any other selector.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you **absolutely must** give in to the nesting temptation you can use `*{ line-height: 1; &,&::before,&::after{ box-sizing: border-box; } }` to self reference the parent element using `&,`

Comment: I understand SASS, this was an arbitrary example.  The question is how to use a * selector.  You mention that SASS views it as just another selector, but in fact it throws a syntax error.  SASS does not like the * character.

Comment: I have accepted your answer.  Please see my comments in the OP.

Answer (score -1):

```
*
　...
  &:before, &:after
    ...
```

`&` stands for the current selector. e.g. `foo { .bar { } }` is `foo .bar`; `foo { &.bar { } }` matches `foo.bar`.

Comment: What's the advantage of doing that in this case?

Comment: @torazaburo: I did not pay attention that the block was the same; had I noticed it, I would probably have answered as you did. But in general, when it specifies exceptions to the more general rules, nesting improves clarity; I thought the user was asking about the general case, and SASS syntax.

Comment: yes he is asking general case and sass/scss syntax.