# * selector in SASS doesn't work?

Tags: css, sass

There is my problem. I'm trying to compile SASS to CSS in Gulp and this is the error I'm getting:

```
 Message:
     styles\main.sass 
 Error: 
     Invalid CSS after "* {": expected "}", was "{"
 >> * { {
    ---^
```

And this is the piece of SASS file the Gulp has problem with:

```
//resets
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Does SASS doesn't accept * selector or it's something else?

//EDIT

Posting whole SASS file:

```
//colors
$red: #ff6347;

//fonts
$font-stack: ‘Times New Roman’, Times, serif;

//resets
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    user-select: none;
}

//placeholders
%upperAndLowerButtonsDivs {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    transition: all 0.35s linear;
}

html, body {
    background-color: $red;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

body {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: $font-stack;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: white;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 525px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#upperButtons {
    text-align: center;
    div {
        @extend %upperAndLowerButtonsDivs;
        &:hover {
            color: $red;
            background-color: white;
        }
    }
}

#timer {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 276px;
    height: 226px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    div {
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

#lowerButtons {
    text-align: center;
    div {
        @extend %upperAndLowerButtonsDivs;
        &:hover {
            color: $red;
            background-color: white;
        }
    }
}

#mode {
    display: block !important;
    cursor: auto !important;
}

#time {
    cursor: auto !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#addTime, #reduceTime {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

#resume {
    display: none !important;
}

@media only screen and(max-width: 590px) {
    //placeholders
    %upperAndLowerButtonsDivsMobile {
        width: 80px;
        line-height: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        margin: 0px;
        letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
        transition: all 0.35s linear;
        margin-top: 25px;   
    }

    #upperButtons {
        margin-bottom: 40px !important;
        div {
            @extend %upperAndLowerButtonsDivsMobile;
        }
    }

    #lowerButtons {
        margin-top: 8px;
        div {
            @extend %upperAndLowerButtonsDivsMobile;
        }
    }

    #timer {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }

    #longBreak {
        line-height: 25px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I believe are the semi-colons. As you said you are using SASS not SCSS, you should check out the [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) syntax. SASS doesn't require semi-colon termination but SCSS does. Removing the semi-colons will solve your problem.

You can test it out by just compiling the first 4 lines without semi-colons

```
//colors
$red: #ff6347

//fonts
$font-stack: ‘Times New Roman’, Times, serif
```

As you can see in this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zENpKo), the code you provided is perfectly fine SCSS.

Answer (score 2):

As is mentioned in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058447/2341603)**, there is nothing special about the **[Universal Selector (`*`)](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Selector/Universal.html)** in SASS; it's a perfectly valid SASS selector.

Your syntax error is coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine, check your code, there must be an error somewhere else.